# How to show user emails on EditText without AccountManager or Permission

Tags: android

I've seen a lot of Apps when I click on the EditText of email it shows a list of the emails that I'm using on my device like Image [image: auto fill email]

And I'm sure it's Not AccountManager since it didn't ask me for permission and not Google smart lock 
Also, I've tried the `AutoFill` service

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editNameInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and programmaticly but it didn't work

```
 editEmail.setAutofillHints(View.AUTOFILL_HINT_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
 editEmail.setImportantForAutofill(IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_YES);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Autofill framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill) provide the feature to fill the previously entered password, credit card number etc etc.

You can set the `autofillhints` to allow this framework to fill in the details.

Follow [Optimize your app for autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize) for more details

Note:

> An autofill service must be configured on your device for your app to
>   use the autofill framework. Although most phones and tablets running
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher ship with an autofill service,
>   we recommend that you use a test service when testing your app

Comment: I've tried it, and  it didn't work, I updated the question please let me know if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: `When using an emulator, you must explicitly set an autofill service because the emulator may not come with a default service` , you sure the auto fill is installed in OS or you followed the steps to install it from sample it, test it to confirm

Comment: I tested it on a real device and I checked the autofill service is Google but nothing worked...